# How to add "jump" in C# script in Unity3d using Character Controller?

Tags: c#, windows, unity-game-engine, game-development

I made it possible for the character to walk in 8 directions, but I don’t know how to add a “jump” to make everything work...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour {

    public CharacterController controller;
    public float speed;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;
    public float turnSmoothTime;

    void Update() {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

        if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f) {
            float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f); 
            controller.Move(direction * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try asking for some help or explanation rather than just asking someone else to do the work for you. We want people to learn in this community rather than just be given the answers :)

Comment: Then can you give advice on how to solve my problem? ;)

Comment: @whathm seems like some OPs don't even understand the meaning of such a comment ^^

Comment: What whathm tries to say is: Your question is off-topic here due to asking for a complete solution/library/tool. Please refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to calculate the angle and the rotation of the character since these are already calculated for you by Unity when you are using the CharacterController class.

To jump, you probably need to assign a button to the jump action.Then, you can check in `Update` whether your jump button is pressed for each frame. 
You can use something like this and add it to the movement command in your code:

```
 public float jumpSpeed = 2.0f;
 public float gravity = 10.0f;
 private Vector3 movingDirection = Vector3.zero;

 void Update() {
     if (controller.isGrounded && Input.GetButton("Jump")) {
         movingDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
     }
     movingDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
     controller.Move(movingDirection * Time.deltaTime);
 }
```

Comment: Might be copied from https://answers.unity.com/answers/574381/view.html?

Comment: I actually referenced Unity's own code example: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html

Comment: Ok, the forum one's then probably from there too :).